# Establishing a connection between Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a complete newbie to Node.js, but I do have some experience with mysql and some other languages.

I am trying to establish a database connection between Node.js and MySQL, however, my terminal keeps on giving me errors. It failed, so I tried to debug it by using "error.stack" as stated from the documentation, that failed also so I'm totally lost now. Can someone please help me to figure out the bug.

Also, can anyone also tell me how to tell Node.js to print out the reason of why it failed to connect to the database like the function "mysql_error()" from PHP.

My original Node.js code:

```
var MySQL = require('mysql');
var DatabaseConnection = MySQL.createConnection({
 host: '10.0.0.25',
 user: 'Admin',
 password: 'Password'
});
DatabaseConnection.connect(function(error) {
 if(!error) {
  console.log("Database is connected");
  return;
 } else {
  console.log("Database is not connected: ");
  console.log(error.stack);
 }
});
```

My result:

```
Database is not connected: 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.0.0.25:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/marc/Documents/JSON_MySQL_Database_Test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/marc/Documents/JSON_MySQL_Database_Test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/marc/Documents/JSON_MySQL_Database_Test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marc/Documents/JSON_MySQL_Database_Test/Database_Test.js:8:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
```

Comment: ECONNREFUSED : this isn't a node problem. Maybe your server isn't listening, or not on that port

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED`  happens when node is not able to connect to given address(ie: `10.0.0.25:3306`). I'd troubleshoot by checking if 
1. the database is running on said port & ip
2. Try to connect to the database using any command line tool from the same machine.

Comment: @explorer, it seems that my script is able to connect to the database given that the script is being executed on the local machine with the database and that the host address is 'localhost'. I'm assuming that some kind of firewall or some kind of ip filtering is in place with the database that's preventing the script from my Mac to be able to connect to the database on my raspberry pi. Do you know where is the configuration file for mysql and the relevant command for the sql database? Thx

Comment: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configuring-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/ The guide is for Ubuntu. You can easily translate that for raspberrypi.